# Visual Studio 2010 debugging ASP .NET MVC 2 app is slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Asp .NET MVC 2 apps started from Visual Studio 2010 are damn in my opinion. It takes 2-5 seconds to refresh or open a new page. Do you have the same problem? Do you know if this ASP .NET MVC 2 debug mode can be somehow sped up?

I work at 64 bit computer, Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Are you talking about initial page load (after a build) being slow, or every page load?

Comment: I've developed several MVC applications but there's no reason for Visual Studio to run slow. You have to be using some strange server configuration. But as @kbrimington said, this may be due to .net compiling the assembly after it was changed and first run. But this is the same for any .net application.

Comment: I find that running my site in IIS proper is *much* faster for page reloads than the stock dev server (cassini).  No idea why that is, but I always develop against local IIS.

Comment: @kbrimington - I am talking about every page load. 
@Robert Koritnik - I haven't changed anything in my server configuration. However I believe that MVC apps started from VS2008 are considerably more responsive than those run started from VS2010.

@Kirk Woll Can you elaborate a little bit on how to develop against local IIS?

Comment: I totally agree - I have been wondering about this - I have 300k pages that take forever to load using VS2k10 and I never had a problem with VS2k8 - it's very frustrating. My specs are the same as yours.

Comment: @kbrimington, when Kirk says develop against local IIS, I believe he means that he configures the project to run through IIS. Project Properties/Web/Servers - "Use Local IIS WebServer."

Answer (score 5):

I had problems with slow Visual Studio debugging when **"Native Code" debugger** was enabled. Try disabling it if it is enabled.

On "Visual Studio 2010" go to:

1. Project Properties ->
2. Web ->
3. Debuggers (bottom of page). ->
4. Disable all exept ASP.NET

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For me, disabling 'Edit and Continue" fixed the problem.

Comment: Where is this? I'm not familiar with "Change and Continue." And nothing is coming up in Google about it.

Answer (score 1):

Menu.Debug.DeleteAllBreakpoints often works, but I still don't know why.

Comment: This worked for me, even though I had no breakpoints set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Intellitrace. Your MVC debugging will go much faster:

1. Click on Tools>Options>Intellitrace.
2. Uncheck "Enable Intellitrace".
3. Click OK
4. Restart debugger.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a similar problem.

I was having a standard ASP.NET and a ASP.NET MVC project in the same solution. 2 development web servers were starting when I was running the debugger.

I just unloaded the standard ASP.NET project (containing a test page and which I did not really use) and everything is now a lot faster.

Hope this helps!