# Build fails with "Could not copy the file.. because it was not found" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2013

I get the following errors when building with Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) several projects:

> Could not copy the file ".." because it was not found.
>
> Could not copy ".." to "..". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
>
> Unable to copy file ".." to "..". The process cannot access the file ".." because it is being used by another process.

I noticed with "Unlocker" that for some strange reason that "QTAgent32.exe" is blocking some of those files.

This seems to be a big issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533411

[Visual Studio "Could not copy" .... during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build/25184328)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling the "Productivity Power Tools" extension in Visual Studio 2013, restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding did it for me. I found this workaround here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533411

Comment: I tried this and I still get the error.  In fact, I can easily re-produce this error anytime simply by Cleaning the Solution and then Rebuilding the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a circular dependency in your code; look for something like:

```
public record foo
{
    foo parent;
    public foo(foo parent){ this.parent = parent; }
}

foo f1 = new();
foo f2 = new foo(f1);
```

Garbage collector will not collect, causing Visual Studio to fail. Make sure you set the parent to null or don't use circular dependencies.

```
public record foo : IDisposable
{
    foo parent;
    public foo(foo parent){ this.parent = parent; }
    void Dispose(){ parent = default; }
}

//this is ok
using foo f1 = new();
using foo f2 = new foo(f1);
```