# VS doesn't want to run simple code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to create new console project in c# and met a problem.
When I debug it, I get empty console...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

    }
}
```

After that i tried to debug it again and got this:

> Error 11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe' because it is being used by another process. ConsoleApplication1

I tried to kill process with task manager, but it starts again right at that second... 
Windows Forms Application debugs good.

Same problem with c++

(scanned PC with Doc. Web and Avast in safe mode and without it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean and build (rebuild)..if it wont help, close Visual Studio, delete **bin** and **obj** folders from your harddrive and launch VS again. Should solve the problem.

Check this related post [Visual Studio "Could not copy" .... during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build)

Oh and try to disable Antivirus (especially if its Avast)..

Comment: can't delete, "The file is open in System"

Comment: Check the answers in the related post..the prebuild action looks working

Comment: Thank you for the link. I still can't delete application.exe from bin folder, but I just moved it to another one and it helped.