# Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll locking issues

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2013, tfs-2015, file-locking

I have a project solution which has several different type of projects; windows service, console apps and web applications being the main ones. The application interfaces with TFS.

The code was written to connect to TFS 2013 and I recently updated it to make it work with TFS 2015. Alongside the code changes I had to manually add the below two dlls:

1. Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll &
2. Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll

The application is now working as expected however I've started encountering [locking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build)

I don't mind stopping the IIS process in my dev environment every now and then even though it's a big annoyance. The problem is this happens during the deployment stage as well.

When a new version of the application is deployed by an automated tool, it is not able to delete the file as IIS is using it and the whole deployment fails because of that. And of the hundred or so dlls used by the web project only this is the only one that remains locked by IIS.

As a workaround I'm stopping IIS before the deployment for now. But I'm really keen to know if there is a workaround/fix to this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you skip the deployment of Microsoft.WITDataStorexx.dll?

Comment: Sadly no because many projects in the solution use the dll actively. I'm rather looking for a solution that gives me a fix with the dll included. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem and I've fixed it by skipping the deployment of that dll if already exists in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there isn't any way to fix this issue for now. But you can only stop your web app rather than the whole IIS service before deployment if these two files are only used by web app. Use [Web Deploy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx) to do this automatically during the deployment.