# Build error in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio

1. Start debugging. During debugging unhandled exception was thrown.
2. Stop debugging.
3. Edit code, start debugging with build, and build error appears

[image: error]

I think Visual Studio don't release these files after first debugging.

This error can appear even if exception wasn't thrown, but if debugging was just stopped.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you please try restarting Visual Studio once and then try rebuilding your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and quickest way is to close VS and kill all VS related processes in Task manager.

Comment: it is boring every time to do this

Comment: I think I found similar question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top
The main idea is to create prebuild actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and then building your project instead of just building your project

Comment: it doesn't help.