# EXEs does not copy on build in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a VB.NET solution containing multiple projects and the expected result is the EXEs in one project should be copied to bin folder of other projects on build. While rebuild solution does this, build solution does not copy the EXEs and even deletes the previously copied EXEs. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Depends what projects are these. NET CORE, netstandard/new project style, old net framework projects. FW version? *"one project should be copied to bin folder of other projects"* -- are they referenced / dependent on each other?

Answer (score -1):

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build) provides two method which may help you solve your problem:

1.Renaming the executable file

2.Another method:

- Closing Visual Studio
- Deleting the bin and obj folders
- Reopening Visual Studio.