# Error handling exceed retry count of 10

Tags: c#, debugging, error-handling

Error 1:

> Error  12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\coursework2.exe" to "bin\Debug\coursework2.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\coursework2.exe' because it is being used by another process.

Error 2:

> Error  11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\coursework2.exe" to "bin\Debug\coursework2.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

I keep repeating getting these two errors. Please explain to me how to solve this.

Comment: Are you trying to copying your executing exe??/

Comment: I think you are trying to build your solution while it's already running in background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689353/visual-studio-2012-warning-msb3026-could-not-copy-dlls OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102859/visual-studio-could-not-copy-during-build

Comment: no i am not trying.. i just trying to execute the windows form

Comment: i read from someone else try to uncheck the readonly box from the window explorer. but everytime i opened the file it just go backs to readonly

Answer (score 19):

I agree with @ahmet that your executable might be already executing while you are trying to build the solution.

1. Open up Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc)
2. Look for executing processes or applications matching your executable name (CourseWorks.exe)
3. Close them
4. Retry

Comment: everytime i try to end process. it just stays there.. nothing happen

Comment: so there is no solution?

Comment: in that case i cannot tell you what your exact problem is but since you are getting a pcocess in the task manager try findign a process thats starting your executable again after shutting it down

Comment: by any chance you know what this mean "System.NullReferenceException" it happens everytime i try to add things from the textbox

Comment: this means an object whoes property you are trying to access is null

Comment: if i send you the code.. do you mind take a look at it please..

Comment: Closing VS and then deleting Bin and Obj folders and then opening VS n building application should work.

Comment: I had the same error. Its worked me. Upvote from my side :)