# Imageresizer seems to add 5 to 6 seconds to all requests and makes debugging very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I am currently evaluating imageresizer for a MVC4 based project and have installed the nuget package (ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig).  However it now takes about 3 mins to get the debugger to attach, build times have grown exponentially and page load times have gone from sub second to 5 to 6 seconds...

I have done no other configuration steps other than install the nuget package, if i remove the package things return to normal.  So i am sure that ImageResizer is the culprit here.  Are there any additional configuration steps i am missing?

Does image resizer have a working folder or something like that where files are written to? if so i guess AV could be to blaim here..

Any ideas on how i can get the performance back to my site as i would love to use dynamic image resizing over statically resized images?

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig adds a **total of 235kb** to your project, and takes *no actions* during startup  except reading from the Web.config file.

You're seeing **3 minute** debugger attach times - that generally [indicates a symbol loading problem, and you can fix that in Visual Studio settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow).

**Any NuGet package you install will cause the same behavior - if the package offers source code and/or symbols**.

I suggest retagging your question as 'nuget' and 'visualstudio'.

Comment: Fairly sure its not a symbol issue as i have already gone through the steps in that question i.e. i have a local symbol cache, ms symbol servers are disabled, and i have copied the pdb's for image resizer into my solution as well.  But even on pages with no images at all the loading time is significantly greater than without having imageresizer installed.  Would it make any difference if the project is running out of a virtual folder, instead of server root?

Comment: Are you running this on a network drive? Have you tried other NuGet packages, and have you had the same behavior for any of them?

Comment: The solution is running locally and I have several nuget packages installed in this solution, and none of them exhibit this behaviour.  As stated in the question when i uninstall ImageResizer the problem disappears.  I will try and replicate the issue with a clean project with only ImageResizer installed.  I should have time over the weekend to profile the project hopefully that will shed some light on the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks. I've had no other reports of this happening, and the latest version has been out for months, so it would be quite strange if this didn't turn out to be specific to your environment.