# Very slow debugging ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, debugging, aspnet-development-server

I have a solution which contains 11 projects. The main project is ASP.NET MVC. When I run the project in debug mode (F5), the main page of the site loaded approximately 2 minutes. Note! Home page of the site is a login form, there's not a lot of sql queries.

Interestingly, when I run the project in without debug mode (ctrl + f5), the main page of the site loaded in a few seconds.

I tried to look for solutions. For example, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow). Unfortunately, I was unable to execute the instructions written by [Zeb Kimmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941702/zeb-kimmel).

I would be glad to any advice and suggestions.

P.S. I have a processor intel core 2 duo e6300, 3gb ram, windows 7 (32 bit).

Comment: i have updated my answer . plz try and let me know

Answer (score 3):

**Visual Studio IDE settings**

- Go to Tools - Options and set the following:
- Projects and Solutions - Build and Run. Check "Only build startup
  projects and dependencies on Run"

This will prevent it building all the projects all the time!

- **Environment – General**
- Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client
  performance"
- Uncheck "Enable rich client visual experience"
- Uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available"
- IntelliTrace – General
- Uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace”

This disables a specific tracing technology most people don't use, that adds major overhead.

**Environment - Startup**

- Set "At Startup" to "Show empty environment"

  Disable "Download content every..."

**PC setup**

1. Get an SSD! We use an Intel SSD caching system, which is improves
   our build times by about 50%. Specifically it's motherboards with
   20GB mATA SSD drives, using  Intel Smart Response Technology  (or is
   it called Rapid Storage Technology collectively?). We have it set to
   "maximized" mode, which means it caches writes as well as reads. I
   suspect, but haven't yet tried, that a pure SSD would improve it
   even more.
2. If you can't get an SSD, defragment drives properly. The built-in XP
   one might not good enough to defragment free space if the drive has
   become heavily fragmented at some point! I used: Auslogics Disk
   Defrag.
3. Exclude virus scan on network, work and VS folders.

**Project specific**

1. Unload projects if you're not maintaining them or are unlikely to
   affect them in your work.

**Refer this links**

[Ways to speedup Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325630/ways-to-speedup-visual-studio-2010)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/09893b7e-8882-49e6-a1df-4b1e0ce82843/tips-for-speeding-up-debugging-stepping-through-code

Comment: thank you for great answer. Unfortunately, I do not see any changes. SSD is very cool. Soon I will buy this disc.