# Slow performance in Visual Studio 2012 update 4 RC when setting a breakpoint

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 update 4 RC.

When I set a breakpoint in my **MVC 4 app (C#)**, the performance goes drastically down. From **<< 1sec. to 40-60 seconds** for a page refresh (if the page appears at all.....)

Disabling all breakpoints bring the performance to a normal level.

How can I set breakpoint without a major performance penalty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I've quit using the Azure Full Emulator and started using the Emulator Express.

- rightclick the azure project
- select properties
- web emulator -> select 'Use Emulator Express'

Answer (score 3):

You may try to delete your `.suo` file but beware as you may loose your personal solution configuration settings for this solution.

You may also try disabling `"Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls"` in **Tools > Options > Debugging > General.**

Also check this related question:- [Visual Studio Debugging/Loading Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow)

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I've already tried deleting the .suo in vain, but disabling the "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" did the trick. This saves me a lot of time . . .

Comment: @RichardDriessen:- You are welcome! Thats great.! You may upvote the answerif that helped you as that will also increase the credibility of the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately the issues has returned, but this time even without setting breakpoint(s) the application sometimes does not even sent a response to a web request.

Comment: @Richard Did you ever get this issue resolved? I'm experiencing the same issue. All suggestions here and on the related question are not helping at all. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I've added my solution to this question, I hope it will help you.