# Visual Studio 2013 - Debugging mode startup speed

Tags: visual-studio

With VS2013 on my machine, new MVC project with no real code written as of yet, the time it takes from F5 (start debugging) until Chrome launches and the page is loaded is about 8 seconds consistently.

On a medium size project, the time is about 20 seconds.

Any tips on how I can speed this up? Any place I can look to try and pinpoint the problem?

Comment: SSD, more ram, upgrade the CPU, ... but is it that bad?

Comment: Already running a retina macbook pro; SSD, plenty of ram, core i7

It is that bad IMO, 20 seconds to startup and begin testing...begins to get annoying.

Comment: Bootcamp or VM? Running in a VM will take a hit.

Comment: Running native, not in a VM

Answer (score 0):

You may try disabling `"Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls"` in **Tools > Options > Debugging > General.**

Also check this [Visual Studio Debugging/Loading Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow)

Comment: How about deleting your .suo file?

Comment: Same as before, no effect. Also tried the symbol trick from the posting you referenced and no luck there either.