# Is it possible to put debug symbol files in RAM?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols

I develop small projects, using ASP.NET MVC 3-5 and Visual Studio 2010/2013. I have a very slow process of debugging. I tried to accelerate the process of debugging using [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow). Unfortunately, the debugging process is still very slow.

Is there some way to put debugging symbols in RAM?

P.S. I have Core 2 duo e6600, 3 GB RAM, 256 GB HDD (90% full).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is what's happening when you're attaching the debugger. It will load all the symbol files into memory so that you can debug the process. This takes time, the best way to improve that performance is to make sure your machine's drive is fast enough (SSD or 10k rpm drive) and that the drive is properly defragmented.

Comment: As I understand that I have a slow process of debugging, because reading debug symbol from the disk into RAM takes a long time, because HDD is slow. So I would like to pre-load symbols in memory.