# Does anyone else see a slowdown in VS 2012 JavaScript debugging after installing VS 2013 Trial?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

**Symptoms**

I recently installed `VS 2013` and I started to notice a slowdown in my `JavaScript` debugging for `VS 2012`.  Each step takes about 7-10 seconds. `C#` debugging seems unaffected.  I did this on a `Windows 7 64 bit` machine.  I followed all of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow?rq=1) to try to resolve it, without any luck.  Other questions on SO had similar answers, so I am not linking them.  Uninstalling `VS 2013` did not resolve the issue.  The only solution was to perform a system restore.

After the system restore I re-installed `VS 2013` and the slowness returned.

Next I installed `VS 2013` on a `Windows 8 64 bit Virtual Machine`.  The symptoms were the same.

**Workaround**

As mentioned the only solution that I have is to perform a system restore to before the install of `VS 2013`.

**Desired Solution**

I would like to have both versions of Visual Studio installed and no slowdowns in debugging.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try or another place to look?