# Slow Debugging of ASP.NET MVC 5 On 2nd, 3rd time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im running an ASP.NET MVC application (in Debug mode) from LocalHost in MS VS 2013 Pro. The application connects to a remote database.

For some reason the application has become much slower 'overnight'. It all used to work smooth up until about a day ago. Now for some reason when I boot my machine up (cold boot) and run the application it works perfectly. But just say I close the application and stop debugging and then run the application again, it is really ultra slow. If I reboot the machine and then run the app everything is back to normal.

So basically, its the 2nd time of debugging (without rebooting whole machine) that its ultra, ultra slow.

Any help would be great!

In the debug window is:

'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\6a721505\90d0028d_2258cf01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\22324533\7092298d_2258cf01\WebMatrix.WebData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\021ff24a\e0638e8c_2258cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\95a37a1e\20a1068d_2258cf01\System.Web.WebPages.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\731993f0\b0ad008d_2258cf01\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\79ff7061\30c4608c_2258cf01\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\c6f94af9\d026df8d_2258cf01\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\63a74605\401bd68c_2258cf01\Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_2.1.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\84014a7d\c0fe7c8c_2258cf01\System.Web.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\e1d9295c\9058168d_2258cf01\WebMatrix.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\App_global.asax.yvi9nkec.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\56b15d59\4084c3ac_d26dcf01\OfficiumWebApp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Users\Sai Lee\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8049ceb4\41eadfc5\assembly\dl3\cf53efd6\306c338f_2258cf01\Owin.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/34/ROOT-1-130443759999540000): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: Looks like your application is not releasing memory on exit.

Comment: Does it help if you just restart your VS?

Comment: Is it also slow without the debugger attached?

Comment: Nope I have to restart whole machine

Comment: And if you stop the 'slow' project and switch to another, is the another project also slow?

Comment: Yes others are also slow

Comment: Did you make any changes to the DB. It might be the communication with your DB that is causing the problem

Comment: May I ask what .Net framework are you targeting in you project, and is there any native code previously coded under .Net 3.5.

Comment: What is it "Just My Code" as a setting for compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Try to apply the following steps for fixing the problem:

**1)** Go to **Tools > Options > Source Control** and set **Current source control …  : None**

**2)** Go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Synchronized Settings** and remove this option by unchecking the checkbox.

**3)** Clean the contents in the following cache folders (*do not delete these folders, instead delete their contents only*) and restart `Visual Studio`:

- Clean the content in **WebSiteCache** folder (can be found in 
   *C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache*)
- Clean the content in **Temporary ASP.NET Files** folder (can be found in 
   *C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files*)

**Note :** If you have `Hardware Acceleration` enabled or if you use the default Visual experience settings in `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015` or `Visual Studio 2013`, you might experience intermittent performance issues, product crashes, or rendering issues. In order to work around these issues,  go to **Tools > Options > Environment > General** and apply the following settings:

[image]

For more information visit:
[You experience performance issues, product crashes, or rendering issues in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215).

**Update :** If the problem is related to debugging, try the workaround on [Visual Studio debugging/loading very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow)

Answer (score 0):

Check, and maybe temporaly disable Antivirus, (Windows Defender, for example) that tries to scan the DLL files every time. Also, if you have 'only' 4GB RAM and think that you need more RAM memory, about 8GB or 16GB

Answer (score 0):

I think that solvation of your problem can be founded in settings of your "Just My Code" profile for compiler. Keeping in mind that you are running your solution from VS - your exception giving that thought:

`Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`.

It is repeating really often. And try to host your app in a real IIS, not IIS Express. Just to be sure.