# Start an ASP.NET MVC 5 projects on IIS Express 8 takes too long to start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 Premium. My project is an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app and Web Api.

When I start the project from Visual Studio I gets too long to start three minutes or more. It is not a very complex app.

I start having this problem I have started add CSS and JS files.

Any idea about how to fix this problem?

I have also test it on building it on Release and it takes so much time to start.

**UPDATE**

Ten minutes from F5 to start the app showing these messages to start asp.net app:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18cc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18e8) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18ec) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18dc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18d8) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18f0) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18e0) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b80) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b7c) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b8c) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x17c4) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b84) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x18e4) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b90) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x10dc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1a90) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x128c) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x978) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1920) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x6b0) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1700) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0xc58) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1bd8) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1668) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b98) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x12b0) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0xf64) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x12fc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1aa0) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1b1c) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1934) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x14c4) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1534) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x11fc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1324) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1bf8) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1370) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1848) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x19e4) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x3dc) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x1588) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\2701212e\44318f32_9468d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\fe5b5890\e6cf8c32_9468d001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\c967a939\e6cf8c32_9468d001\System.Web.WebPages.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\2e9ccefa\8ee38d33_9468d001\WebActivatorEx.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\79fc58cb\ccfc5431_9468d001\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\28993618\620fad31_9468d001\System.Web.Optimization.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_1.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\2f51f27c\2aaf2630_9468d001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\d4d179a6\a0e43634_9468d001\EntityFramework.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\2007e2f6\fe453934_9468d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\ad2ca3aa\114a89c2_dd78d001\Invescontrol.Trazabilidad.China.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\1b55a4b2\facf5f30_9468d001\Ionic.Zip.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\b42fca30\060b3631_9468d001\log4net.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\d0b2cd19\0e8cf532_9468d001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\9bc872ef\8a7a4633_9468d001\Ninject.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\1ac4aa3c\84b47333_9468d001\Ninject.Web.Common.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\b173aabf\94a96033_9468d001\Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\7ec47f06\eef2ea31_9468d001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\252c81d8\886e8a32_9468d001\System.Web.Helpers.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\557ec146\7ad62832_9468d001\System.Web.Http.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\c940b70c\b84d5132_9468d001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\33f8290b\92ee7331_9468d001\System.Web.Razor.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\841976e7\61b55cc5_dd78d001\TRZF.Common.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\51580d11\b1c063c2_dd78d001\TRZF.Data.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\5104e612\d14e71c5_dd78d001\TRZF.Data.SqlServer.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\a3d24447\48f07f89_e078d001\TRZF.Web.API.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\df1156f2\e183d4c2_dd78d001\TRZF.Web.API.Models.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\3c756b2f\a11567c5_dd78d001\TRZF.Web.Common.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\assembly\dl3\5409e797\cc5ab633_9468d001\WebGrease.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\Users\Uic18.IC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\ef02c987\dbd5285d\App_global.asax.2lftm7dd.dll', símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.resources.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Administrado (v4.0.30319)): se cargó 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll', se omitió la carga de símbolos. Se optimizó el módulo y se habilitó la opción 'Solo mi código'.
'iexplore.exe' (Script): 'Código de script (Windows Internet Explorer)' cargado. 
El subproceso '<Sin nombre>' (0x14f4) terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: If your project is set to compile views this can slow it down.  Worth checking in the `proj` file that this is not set to true `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

Comment: No, I don't have set `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` on my csproj file. I don't have any entry with name `<MvcBuildViews>`.

Comment: Are you running any Visual Studio Extensions? If you start a completely fresh MVC project with nothing in it, is it also slow to start?

Comment: I have updated my question with Result window contents.

Comment: @EdSpencer I have installed Productivity Power Tools. But, it was installed at the first time and I'm getting this problem after I have started adding css and js to my views.

Comment: @VansFannel Try to disable symbol loading Tools\Options\Debugging\General\Enable source server support .. also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow

Comment: @Amitd That option was disabled.

Comment: I have tried another ASP.NET MVC projects and they load fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there is the answer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/04/26/asp-net-application-loads-slowly-the-first-time.aspx

> In ASP.NET web application, if you use some [Authenticode Signed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(v=VS.85).aspx) .NET >assemblies, the application will connect to internet to validate the digital >certificates. When the server has no access to internet, this certificate       >authentication process will not end until timeout.

Comment: No, I don't have that kind of assemblies. The problem is when I press F5, it gets too long to start.

Comment: @VansFannel Understood, maybe you are using DB migrations.. in depends on settings  - Migrations could drop and restore your database and it takes some time to finish.