# Starting Unit Test in Visual Studio very slow, repeatedly loading/unloading same dll

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

**Problem**

I'm having serious delays (several minutes) in starting up a Unit Test and it doesn't seem to matter if I'm debugging or not.

When debugging I can see in the output window there is one package that is repeatedly being loaded and unloaded again. This happens literally thousands of times.

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 929): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.AssemblyResolver\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.AssemblyResolver.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 929): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.AssemblyResolver\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.AssemblyResolver.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Dependency finder domain): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing.dll'
```

**I tried ...**

- running Visual Studio 2013 as administrator.
- the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115731/632336
  (Enable Just My Code & Load all Symbols), but when I click the button
  to load all symbols Visual Studio simply crashes. (sometimes
  immediately, sometimes after finished loading)
- enabling/disabling Microsoft Symbol Servers, which makes no
  difference.
- starting up Visual Studio with logging enabled but there is nothing
  that seems out of the ordinary or related to my problem.
- Creating a new empty test project from scratch. Same problem

Comment: It's not very helpful, but we've found that disabling Deployment in the test settings file will significantly reduce the delay before starting the first test.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue and is causing roughly 15 to 20 minutes of build time. Has anybody come to a solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my dev box.
I opened fiddler and found a lot of calls being made to 'symweb'.

So, I created a fiddler auto-responder rule to drop these calls.
After this, the delay before starting the test reduced to less than a second.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a definitive answer because it applies to Visual Studio 2015, but it might help some people.

We recently installed a "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" update (via Extensions & Updates) and since then the slow discovery of unit tests has been resolved. Instead of taking roughly 2 minutes to start up a single unit test, it now takes only a couple of seconds.

The extension was updated from Version 14.1.11107.0 to 14.1.21111.0