# ASP.NET slow startup (symbol loading)

Tags: asp.net, performance, visual-studio, web-services

I have some major performance issues regarding my ASP.NET web application. Navigation between pages etc. is fine, but the initial startup (in any mode) takes up to several minutes. Visual Studio seems to be busy loading symbols in this long period of time - especially temporary asp.net files... I've tried several different supposed solutions that I've found on Google; like caching the symbols, enabling just my code, deleting all breakpoints, deleting the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and most of the tips on this site:
http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx
and this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/
, but without any luck - not even a slight performance improvement.
I don't really know how to troubleshoot it properly, so feel free to ask me to try something - I'm spending almost en hour every day waiting for my application to start, so I'm ready to try anything. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

**EDIT:** I looks like it loads the symbols for the Temporary ASP.NET Files every time, instead of using the ones already there, and there is SO many files that it makes sense that it takes a while to load them all... Is there a way to stop it from loading them all from the beginning on every single startup?

Answer (score 2):

For me the best solution for slow first load after some modifications made was to set this in web.config of my developer machine:

```
<compilation batch="false"></compilation>
```

> When an ASP.NET website is loaded for the first time, it pre-compiles
>   all your pages and user controls. Once done, everything runs faster.
>   This is great for production websites, but horrible for your
>   development machine. Why?  When programming, you’re usually only
>   modifying a page or two (or back-end code). You’ll iteratively make a
>   change, compile, launch the website, test, and start over; often
>   dozens of times. A two minute compile/load time (like we had) forces
>   you to lose focus and get distracted. The following setting makes
>   pre-compilation more selective, making the first load time massively
>   faster in development scenarios. On my machine, it cut the first load
>   time from around 74 seconds to 6 seconds.

You can check other performance tips here: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't actually tried this before, but unfortunately still no luck; Visual Studio still spends a good minute or so loading symbols. I've also tried most of the other tips you are referring to, but again with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow

Comment: Yes. I've tried several of the proposed solutions there, but I have the same issue as as the first comment to the accepted answer; The Microsoft Symbols doesn't seem to be a problem, but rather the loading of my own symbols.

Comment: You can play with manual symbol loading as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/ and here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/

Comment: Yea, I've also tried those... I was hoping for some nontraditional tips from someone with the same issue. I appreciate your effort though :)