# Visual studio 2012 doesn't work when hitting play button

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a asp.net project that I have run many times without issue.  Yesterday for some reason when I hit the play button it looks like it is compiling in the output window but then it just sits there.  The hour glass is showing on the cursor but no response from VS.  At times it will open internet explorer but then it will continually show "Waiting for localhost" on the tab.  I did delete the *.suo file and it didn't seem to fix it.

I'm running visual studio professional 2012 Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5.
My .net framwork version is 4.6.01055.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: @jerru Try to clear the cache of the VS and try again

Comment: I cleared the cache and it is still trying to do something.  I have restarted many times thinking that would help, but it did not.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding your project but if that doesn't work it is a high chance that something is wrong with your code and it we will need to see it.

Comment: This happens with multiple projects so I don't think it is a code issue.

Comment: Does this also occur when you create a default project and attempt to run that?

Comment: Null,  What do you mean by a default project?  Should I create a basic project and see if it does the same?

Comment: Yes just a default project without anything added/edited etc. See if it does the same as a way to slim down the possible culprit

Comment: I just created a simple asp.net project and ran it and it opened the browser faster but it is just sitting there waiting for localhost.  After a couple minutes the page appeared.  I stopped debugging and restarted the test project and now it opens up fast and displays fast.

Comment: This could possibly be a port issue, make sure your firewall and/or your application ports.

Also be aware that this may be your virus software, try temporarily disabling it.

Comment: I disabled real-time protection on my forefront virus scanner and I tried starting a different project.  Now it is sitting on "Loading symbols for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageINspector.Loader.dll from Microsoft Symbol Servers"  The progress bar does not show anything.

Comment: That sounds like an unresponsive symbol server, I suggest you alter your symbol settings to get around this, hopefully this will fix your issues finally too

Comment: Null, It does look like it's a symbol issue.  I did clear the symbol cache and I pointed to the microsoft public server.  When I start the debugging at the bottom it says Loading symbols for ....   That is what is taking a long time.  Is there a setting I'm missing that needs to be changed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in this link and it fixed my issue.  It was a symbol loading issue.  So far I tried a couple of projects and they loaded pretty quick.  Thanks again for help everyone.

[Visual Studio Debugging/Loading Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow)