# VS 2017 - Very slow (laggy) when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I debug my solution, vs 2017 is very laggy and slow it's like it has to operate something heavy in the background.

So it stops "responding" every 5 seconds for 2 seconds, which is very annoying.
Any suggestions?

EDIT (tried suggestions):

- Browser Link is turned off
- Stopped customer feedback

Comment: I had this once with BrowserLink running. I turned it off and everything ran smoothly again, may be a red herring but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, but did not work :/

Comment: Did you try stopping customer feedback? It's Help --> Send Feedback --> Settings... --> No, I would not like to participate

Comment: Unfortunately, yes - I always deny that

Comment: Do you have intellitrace turned on?

Comment: Yes - with "IntelliTrace events only" enabled |
Disabling does also not help.

Comment: My problem - similar symptoms, very slow debugging of ASP.NET project - was solved by yet another solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290607/889779 - might be useful for someone who stumble across this question in the future

Comment: And for people who arrived at this question after 15.8.1 was released: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/315338/vs-2017-1581-debugging-extremely-slow.html

Answer (score 98, accepted):

After some additional investigation I found this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26064/slow-debug-in-vs-2017.html)
Unchecking **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging** in Tools → Options → Debugging → General did the trick!

Unchecking  **Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET**  in
Tools → Options → Debugging → General
makes a huge difference in performance.

Comment: report it to Microsoft so that they can fix it with an update for vs2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017

Comment: YAY! wow I was losing my mind with "click and wait >5 seconds" for EVERY action... THANKS!

Comment: I have the same issue, but already had "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging" disabled, so that doesn't seem to fix it entirely :-(

Comment: In our case running in Community was much faster than running in Enterprise.  Not sure what feature(s) Enterprise might have that Community does not that would cause this?  Anybody have speculations?

Comment: YEAH! it worked for me! debugging was a nightmare! big thanks.

Comment: In addition, also disable IntelliTrace: Tools > Options IntelliTrace. Now FINALLY it will be fast like you remembered it.

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Features like this really shouldn't go out unless they are scalable.

Answer (score 14):

If disable Diagnostic Tools don't fix the problem try to disable IntelliTrace,
Unchecking Enable IntelliTrace, in  Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace.
Work for me.

Comment: IntelliTrace is a pretty useful tool. Rather than disabling the whole thing, it's best to just disable the event that is slowing things down. **Tools → Options → IntelliTrace → IntelliTrace Events**. For me, once I **disabled ADO.NET event logging** things were speedy again.

Answer (score 14):

I have tried disabling few things myself just to see what is causing it. The only thing that did work for me is Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)".

I'm using VS2017 Enterprise v15.2 for Asp.net WebForms.

Comment: Thx. Disabling Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE) finally did the trick for me

Comment: @NickG. glad to hear from you :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hiding the Threads window** did the trick for me.

Comment: Comment on why the downvote? If your app is running with many threads and this window is showing it most certainly slows down the debugging experience significantly

Comment: It is mentioned here: [Make Debugging Faster with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/)

Comment: Yep, this very clearly solved the slowness of the debugger for me! Thanks a lot for the tip!
What is strange though is that I always had the "threads" window visible, but the slowness was not always occurring.

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to hide the window just by activating another tab, so the "threads" window is not in sight. That is probably the reason why the slowness was sometimes there and sometimes not, depending on which tab page was selected.

Answer (score 4):

I also experience the lag when "Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)" is checked.   And Turning off the "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging" did not help.

However, I also noticed that when I F12 for Chrome Developer Tools, then lag time goes away and the app performs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. Disabling Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE) finally did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

Only one thing that helped me was disabling Debugger option of Resharper.
If you use **Resharper**, try to UNCHECK **"Show local variables values in editor"** in menu: **Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Debugger**.

[image: Resharper's Debbuging options]

It helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was removing all the following folders in the solution's directory:

- `.vs`
- `x64`
- `Debug`
- `Release`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced same problem.  In debug mode, my webforms project ran very slowly.  When using Ctrl+ F5, it ran quickly (as it does when deployed).  I found a try/catch block that was executing 45 times.  It wasn't doing anything, it was just trapping an error that I had made.  I fixed the error and, when removing the try-catch block - voila! -- back to full speed.

So if you're experiencing this problem and you've tried all the solutions above (I did), look for a try catch block that is firing often. [ Fix your error :) ] and then remove the try-catch block.  I can't believe the difference it has made.  Shouldn't have made any difference at all, of course, since the try-catch block wasn't doing anything, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, for me helped disabling **Enable Edit and Continue** options in Tools → Options → Debugging → General.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up getting **Debug**=>**Attach To Process** working... even [tried ALL the solutions on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115731/175679) (*2-pages worth*).

#### Solution

Use [ReAttach VS IDE Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach). This bypasses the need to ever use the **Attach to Process** dialog again if it's a process you've recently attached to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2017 Enterprise edition, try disable IntelliTrace feature
 (Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace)

with this feature turned off, the laggy behavior went away even keeping the Diagnostic tools turned on (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging)

Comment: There could be many other reasons why your app might get slow while debugging, if the suggested solution above does not work for you doesn't mean it won't in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is because of a **Realtime scan in Antivirus.**

"**Add exceptions**" Visual Studio files/folders for your Antivirus

C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2017 \ Professional \ Common7 \ IDE \ devenv.exe

C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 201

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem where the program was running slower if started from visual studio, turned out to be too many threads, like alot of new System.Threading.Thread() in a loop etc. I switched the code to use the ThreadPool instead with Task etc and the slowness went away.

Answer (score 0):

choosing "Load only specified modules" did the trick (**Tools=>Options=>Debugging=>Symbols**)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a break point with a condition that was never met. I had forgotten about about this break point altogether. Sometimes adding a simple condition to a break point can slow down the debugging speed a lot.

Just adding this in case it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to **many exceptions occuring** in your C# application. Experiment with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code. Check whether there are many exceptions being logged in the Output window.

According to the article [Make Debugging Faster with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/),

> When debugging managed (.NET) code, every time an exception occurs,
> regardless of whether it is handled or not, the target application is
> paused (just like it hit a breakpoint) so the runtime can notify the
> debugger that an exception occurred. This is so the debugger can stop
> if you have the debugger set to break on the first chance exceptions,
> if not, the application is resumed. This means that if a significant
> number of exceptions occur it will significantly slow down how fast
> the application can execute.
>
> You can tell if a large number of exceptions are occurring by looking
> in the Output window. If you see a lot of “A first chance exception of
> type…” or “Exception thrown…” messages in the Window this is likely
> your problem.
>
> To diagnose this potential issue, you may need to disable “Just My
> Code”, as when it is enabled the first chance exception messages do
> not appear for exceptions occurring in “external code” but the
> notification overhead is still present. Once you’ve diagnosed whether
> first chance exceptions are your issue (or not), remember to turn on
> again “Just My Code” for all the other good reasons.

Enabling Just My Code allowed me to break on exceptions that were triggering in my application and fix them. After fixing just two exceptions, my application is running smoothly in Debug.

Answer (score -1):

workaround that I used was to run msvcmon.exe locally with admin mode before starting the debugger. Then start the attach window and providing the remote debugging port.