# Some Web Api endpoints very slow when Visual Studio debugger is on

Tags: debugging, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

When I run our Web Api (.NET Framework 4.6.2project on IISExpress with the Visual Studio debugger on, some of our endpoints are really slow: 16 seconds instead of 200ms, or as in the example 8 seconds instead of 3 seconds.

[image]

When I stop the debugger of Visual Studio and the application is still running on IISExpress in the background, the API is very fast again.

I guess it could will be a setting in Visual Studio, but I can't find it.
I have searched and tried some settings which I found on StackOverflow for example:
- 'Just my code', which is on
- Symbols are cached in a folder and Microsoft Symbol Servers is off
- Browser link is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I've solved it using following Stackoverflow response:
[Why is DbContext.SaveChanges 10x slower in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925972/why-is-dbcontext-savechanges-10x-slower-in-debug-mode)
As he states:
Ok, so the reason debug mode was exceptionally slow was because Visual Studio's Intellitrace was recording each ADO.NET event ( all 20, 000 of them ) generated by Entity Framework.

So Tools-> Options -> IntelliTrace and Uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace" fixed the issue.

Or one can also just filter out the ADO.NET events by going to Tools->Options -> IntelliTrace -> IntelliTrace Events and uncheck ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

> Some Web Api endpoints very slow when Visual Studio debugger is on

Besides, l think you can try these steps:

**1)** uncheck the option **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging** in `Tools`-> `Options` ->`Debugging`->`General`

**2)** please make sure that you have disable **Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET** in
`Tools`->`Options`->`Debugging` ->`General`

In addition, if you are using VS 2019 Enterprise edition, try disable **IntelliTrace** feature (`Tools` -> `Options` -> `IntelliTrace`)

More info you could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764166/vs-2017-very-slow-laggy-when-debugging).