# What does 'Enable Edit and Continue' do in the Debuggers section in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I've been trying to improve my Visual Studio debug startup time. I've gotten it from 45 seconds to about 25 seconds to load up my site for debugging. I've been following advice from this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow).

One option suggests I un check the 'Enable Edit and Continue' button under project -> web -> debuggers.

This makes the time Visual Studio takes to open up, load my site and ready to use/debug about 5 seconds, down from 25.

But I'm concerned what it does, or doesn't do/allow?

It seems like I can still edit html/razor, javascript code while debugging, so what does it do?

Comment: It lets you change code while debugging without having to restart your program/site.  C# and vb.net code.

Comment: I can do that even with the button unchecked! Please look at my last line in the post

Comment: Your last line mentioned that JS code could dynamic change and work immediately during debugging?  I just tested it in my side with VS2017 15.6.3, however, it won't work no matter i check "Enable edit and continue", as i know the option Edit and Continue only with the main executable code

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here, but I just added a new line of Javascript code, hit the reload button in the browser and set a new breakpoint on that new line. It seems to be stopping on that new breakpoint for me. Is there some other way to utilize dynamic code that I'm unaware of? I also added a new HTML tag, hit reload and see the changes in the browser.

Comment: "You can disable or enable Edit and Continue in the Options dialog box at design time. You cannot change this setting while you are debugging." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396