# Visual Studio 2010 slow debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2010. When I start debugging it works slowly.

Internet Explorer opens, but the website loads extremely slowly.

My workmate and me work on the same project and he doesn't have any problem like that.

My hardware is 4G memory + Intel Core i5 CPU 3.20 GHz.
I stopped my anti-virus program but it couldn't be resolved.

Comment: Try to delete your `SolutionFile.suo` (next to `SolutionFile.sln`) and re-open Visual Studio. It helped me.

Comment: This unfortunately seems to be a known and unresolved defect. I've never tried the suo option, let me know how that goes. You could also try rebooting.

Comment: Are you working on the same Solution on a shared network drive? i.e. exactly the same files on the same disk? This causes the problem you describe.

Comment: @Greg B that's atleast not the case for me, my machine is a dual core xeon with 6GB ram allocated to my VM and I've seen this behavior semi-frequently when working on local files.

Comment: Do you have Intellitrace running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: very slow web applications debugging!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707977/visual-studio-2010-very-slow-web-applications-debugging)

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks chris for link , I found solution in this link and it was really easy. Problem was breakpoints, delete all breakpoints thats all :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem for over a year! And I solved it :)

I took me about 20 seconds to start debugging, and about 1 minute to stop it. It also took 2 minutes to load the solution! My colleague had NO problems with the same solution.

I found my way out of it by a coincidence.

I CHANGED the NAME of the solution, and things suddenly happened 30 times faster.

I CHANGED the solution name back and it slowed down again!

This is probably a FUBAR error made by the Microsoft development team. Don't try to figure out why it happens :)

Comment: Did your old project name have special characters like spaces?  Did you end up with a new suo file when changing names, and then end up using the old corrupted suo when changing it back?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a IPV6 issue (that shows itself in windows vista/7 when using firefox or IE). I've had that at work and this is what made pages load instantly when using localhost (instead of the 20+ seconds that could happen on image-heavy websites I was developing).

**IPv6** (taken from [Firefox cannot load websites but other programs can](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20cannot%20load%20websites%20but%20other%20programs%20can) )

> Firefox supports IPv6 by default, which may cause connection problems on certain systems. To disable IPv6 in Firefox:
>
> In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
>
> The *about:config "This might void your warranty!"* warning page may appear. Click **I'll be careful, I promise!**, to continue to the about:config page.
>   In the Filter field, type **network.dns.disableIPv6**.
>   In the list of preferences, double-click **network.dns.disableIPv6** to set its value to true.

**For Internet Explorer**, try using http://127.0.0.1:PORT_NUMBER/ where PORT_NUMBER is the port you can see in your address bar. If the loading of the page is faster, then you might want to go check the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS file and make sure the only line mentioning localhost looks like *127.0.0.1            localhost*.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable set. Getting symbols or pdb files for the assemblies used by your application from a symbol server could be the cause of the slow startup of your application when debugging. You can also look at the symbols setting in VS>Tools>Options>Debugging. Also, take a look at the output window and the status bar down at the bottom in VS when your app is loading and taking a long time to see what VS is busy doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to ASP.NET applications, but disabling the 'Show Parameter Values' option in the Call Stack window's context menu considerably speeds up the debugger on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check.
1. Remove all the parameters in the watch list.
2. Build >> Config Manager , Check the Configuration Mode: Debug/Release.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. I could make it better by deleting the Folder created in the temporary aspnet folder. For that you need to close the solution that you have opened and then delete. I don't know if there is any other solution.