# From Windows 7 Professional Visual Studio 2010 takes over a 2 minutes to load the document in the editor window

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, asp-classic

I reformatted my laptop and reinstalled vs2010, now every time I open a asp classic solution the following occurs:

- solution explorer loads
- tabs for the pages left open from last time appear
- wheels spin for about 2-3 minutes before I can begin work

It was fast and responsive on Windows XP pro...

Laptop specs
Intel i7 M620 2.67GHZ
4GB
32 Bit

Comment: I've already updated to SP1, no difference, as well as trying to disable hardware accelaration through Tools --> Options --> General

Comment: Do any messages appear in the VS statusbar during loading?

Comment: There are a few suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707977/visual-studio-2010-very-slow-web-applications-debugging Try the "Native Code" debugger one.

Comment: I'm not debugging anything, the issue is to load the ide.

Comment: @Jan-Peter Vos - Blank, it doesn't read anything on status bar.

Comment: You could try to delete the .suo file next to the solution file. (This should contain only user settings, but keep a copy somewhere to be safe). Also you could try to check if there are references to network locations/network services somewhere in the solution or Visual Studio configuration. Maybe something you unblocked in the firewall on your previous installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run svn cleanup on the directory.  Not sure how that was affecting VS2010, but it was.  Now the app loads up in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your virus scanner.  I had a lot of trouble with vs2010 having VERY long load times until I added exceptions to my build paths in Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: First, it's the same virus scanner installed by the org as on my laptop before upgrading to Windows7, same EPO policy and everything.  Second, HA!. I already and modified my registry to shut it off completely as I also thought it might be the cause.  Third, who installs enterprise level virus scanning software but lets the user shut it off? Derp!!!