# Visual Studio slows down excessively

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My installation of Visual studio eats up memory like a starved pig.  Depending on what I'm doing, after a while, it's too slow and I have to reload it.  Typically, devenv.exe will get to around 700 MB before I have to reload it.

I would expect that it's slowing down because of some excessive page swaps or something.

I read somewhere that Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F12 helps, but it does nothing.

Is there any fixes for this, or at least anything that will allow me to run it for longer till it explodes my ram, ie starts to run slow at 4gb rather than 700mb.

I have Windows 7 x64 with 8GB ram. Using Virgin anti virus stuff.

I have lots of Addons running, I have a suspition that it might be resharper that's causing it to slow.

The number of projects or solutions is irrelevant, as I can run a single winforms project with about 50 lines of code and after a few dozen debugs etc, it'll still be like trying  flog a dead horse.

Ta.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about your situation?  What does your solution look like (in particular how many projects and what kind)?  What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: I think that as VS is 32 bits (yes it's a shame), it won't be able to eat more than 2GB of ram. And when you have a lot of projects / file + hungry addons like resharper... this will be quickly be filled. Never tried, but maybe the 3GB switch can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: very slow web applications debugging!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707977/visual-studio-2010-very-slow-web-applications-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense has been known to cause problems, you may want to try to disable it.

Also I had BIG problems with my Anti virus (Kaspersky), the newer versions use a new 'signature' technique that brought mine to a crawl.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, the intellisense comment isn't true.  Intellisense is one of many systems which depend on the semantic information generated by the compiler.  Turning off intellisense may help typing perf but won't shrink VS memory usage by any conceivable amount

Comment: I came across the so called 'Issue' when I was having problems, in my case it made no difference but many people reported a significant increase in speed. Not sure if this is still the case as VS is more mature now, my issue was a while ago.

Comment: It can affect typing performance but it's unlikely to affect the memory foot print.

Comment: Kaspersky did't slow down for me on Windows 10 with VS2013 but can slow down internet while updating

Comment: Visual Studio eats 1GB of ram onmy 6GB PC but does not slow down